# Need primer for a Msbuild newbie

Tags: .net, msbuild, release-management, build-management

We maintain a medium sized windows application developed in vb/c# .net in work. Still now the build and deploy process for this app is manual. I am determined to make this process automated using MSBuild on which i have no knowledge still now.

Our app has a simple build structure, set of projects already grouped into four solutions(.sln) and just need to build the four slns in an order. And then publish a project(which is part of the last sln to be built) to a directory. That is it. A simple process which is already consuming 30 mins of manual build time and i'm pretty sure that this can be accomplished without manual interference using msbuild in atleast 1/4 th of the time.

All my goals set good, i started looking around web for MSBuild resources to accomplish my process but may be looking around many things confused me. Need a pointer or a good explanation on how to start and where to start for my simple scenario. Help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This sounds like a very easy script to write. Even a batch file would do:

```
msbuild \path\to\first.sln /p:Configuration=Release
msbuild \path\to\second.sln /p:Configuration=Release
msbuild \path\to\third.sln /p:Configuration=Release
msbuild \path\to\fourth.sln /p:Configuration=Release
call deploy
```

Of course, much better would be to have a server running, say [CruiseControl.NET](http://confluence.public.thoughtworks.org/display/CCNET/Welcome+to+CruiseControl.NET), that gives a web interface into the build status and history.

In MS Build, there are two main control points for the caller: The Target and its Properties. The Target is what to compile, resources, compilation, deployment, etc. The Properties control how that Target is built.

You can control the configuration using the **Configuration** property (see above). If you open your *.*proj files, you will notice `PropertyGroup` elements. These are settable via the commandline using the `/p` arg.

Here are the specs for the two args:

```
/target:<targets>  Build these targets in this project. Use a semicolon or a
                 comma to separate multiple targets, or specify each
                 target separately. (Short form: /t)
                 Example:
                   /target:Resources;Compile

/property:<n>=<v>  Set or override these project-level properties. <n> is
                 the property name, and <v> is the property value. Use a
                 semicolon or a comma to separate multiple properties, or
                 specify each property separately. (Short form: /p)
                 Example:
                   /property:WarningLevel=2;OutDir=bin\Debug\
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But how do i set configuration options and all? For e.g i debug my app setting projs in DEbug mode but the script should always build in Release mode.  Thanks again for your quick reply.

Comment: I have added details. It's all quite simple and well worth mastering. MS Build can automate **a lot**.

Answer (score 1):

[Here's a good guide](http://dotnet.org.za/cjlotz/archive/2008/01/15/continuous-integration-from-theory-to-practice-2nd-edition.aspx) that has a lot of great information on MSBuild, Continuous Integration and CuriseControl.NET.  Definitely a good place to start.