# Keyboard shortcuts for Debug and Release builds

Tags: visual-studio

It's always bothered me that the same buttons (F6 or Shift-F6) are used to Build a solution or project whether it's a Debug or Release build. For example, if someone forgets to double-check that drop-down first, they could accidentally start a Release build and if the project's configured so the \bin is on a shared dev server as it is in my team, that can screw up other developers as they're working.

What I'd like to do is create two keyboard shortcuts to explicitly *Build As Debug* and *Build As Release*, say `Ctrl-B,D` and `Ctrl-B,R` so the shortcuts will **always** do the right kind of build regardless of what the dropdown selection says.

Is this possible in Visual Studio as a keyboard shortcut setting, or would I have to create a macro or something?

Answer (score 1):

You can probably use AutoHotkey to set up your keyboard shortcut/macro. But I wouldn't do it that way. What's to stop a user from accidentally hitting F6, or accidentally pressing Ctrl-B,R instead of Ctrl-B,D.

I'd make a batch file to create the release straight from source control, using MSBuild. Then you don't have to worry about whether everything's been checked in.

See nice answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/931518/61697) to get started with MSBuild, it's not that tricky. You'll find automating the release process is a breath of fresh air. And it will be simple to modify your script to deploy for production.